# Userform listbox rowsource not populating

Tags: excel, listbox, userform, vba

I have a userform with an `OK` and `Cancel` button and a listbox. It is supposed to populate using this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.StartUpPosition = 0
Me.Top = Application.Top + (Application.Height / 2) - (Me.Height / 2)
Me.Left = Application.Left + (Application.Width / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)

With Me.ListBox1
    .RowSource = ""
    .ColumnCount = 7
    .ColumnWidths = "80;100;20;1;20;1;1000"
    .RowSource = Sheets("BOH Database").Range("H9:N14").Address
  '  .RowSource = Sheets("BOH Database").Range("H9:N" & Sheets("BOH Database").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Address
End With

End Sub
```

Neither RowSource statements work. I have tried clearing RowSource before filling it again. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I've added the code i currently have here as it doesn't show properly in the comment:
I'm using this code based on yours and it's crashing the sheet:

```
With Me.ListBox1
 .ColumnCount = 7
 .ColumnWidths = "80;100;20;1;20;1;1000"
 .RowSource = "'" & Sheets("BOH Database").Name & "'!" & Sheets("BOH Database") _
    .Range("H9:N" & Sheets("BOH Database").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Address
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an incorrect way to do it. The syntax is

```
ListBox1.RowSource = "SheetName!RangeAddress"
```

So if your sheet name is say `Sheet1` then the above becomes

```
ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!H9:N14"
```

Also since your sheet name has a space, you will have to add `'` before and after the sheet name.

Try this

```
 ListBox1.RowSource = "'BOH Database'!H9:N14"
```

Or in your way...

```
With Sheets("BOH Database")
    ListBox1.RowSource = "'" & .Name & "'!" & .Range("H9:N14").Address
End With
```

Comment: I'm using this code based on yours and it's crashing the sheet:

With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 7
    .ColumnWidths = "80;100;20;1;20;1;1000"
    .RowSource = "'" & Sheets("BOH Database").Name & "'!" & Range("H9:N" & Sheets("BOH Database").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Address
End With

Comment: Are you still facing a problem?

Comment: Yes, as above the sheet is crashing on the .RowSource line

Comment: The code that you have works just fine for me. May I see your workbook?

Comment: I am actually still having problems. The userform opens fine the first time it is opened and then crashes the second time. Any ideas, or should i start a new question for this? Wondering if it is overusing memory, it is 7 wide by 500 high

Comment: The problem was conditional formatting. I fixed it by removing and re-applying the formatting after the listbox inserts a row into the sheet. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
Sub lbxChange () 
    Dim sname as string 
    Dim ws as worksheet 
    Set sname = combobox1.value 
    Set ws = sheets(sname) 
    Listbox1.rowsource = ws.range("a1:d10") 
End sub
```

Not work !!!!