# VBA Type Mismatch (13)

Tags: excel, typing, vba

I have two option buttons on a user form (SecurityRadio and SafteyRadio). When I click on Security radio, I want to apply a filter to a sheet name "Security" and then assign that new range to a variable name. For SwitchesRadio, I want the same procedure to happen but with a different sheet.

However, when I select the SwitchesRadio and click on the Go button my code errors when I try to assign the new range to a listbox on a different user form. The error is Run-Time error 13,"Type mismatch" on .ListBox2.. near the end (see comment). Any idea how I can fix this?

```
Private Sub GoButton_Click()
Dim Security As Worksheet, Switches As Worksheet, CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastAddressCurrent1 As Range, LastRowCurrent1 As Long, LastColCurrent1 As Long
Dim LastAddressCurrent2 As Range, LastRowCurrent2 As Long, LastColCurrent2 As Long
Dim RA_Range As Range, Comp_Range As Range

If SwitchesRadio Then
    Set CurrentSheet = Sheets("Switches")
ElseIf SecurityRadio Then
    Set CurrentSheet = Sheets("Security")
Else
    MsgBox "Please select a product type to continue"
End If

'retrieve the last cell row number and column
With CurrentSheet
    Set LastAddressCurrent1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastRowCurrent1 = LastAddressCurrent1.Row
    LastColCurrent1 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

CurrentSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowCurrent1, LastColCurrent1)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="RA"
    With CurrentSheet
    Set LastAddressCurrent2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastRowCurrent2 = LastAddressCurrent2.Row
    LastColCurrent2 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
Set RA_Range = CurrentSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowCurrent2, LastColCurrent2))
CurrentSheet.ShowAllData
CurrentSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowCurrent1, LastColCurrent1)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Comp"
    With CurrentSheet
    Set LastAddressCurrent2 = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastRowCurrent2 = LastAddressCurrent2.Row
    LastColCurrent2 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
Set Comp_Range = CurrentSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRowCurrent2, LastColCurrent2))
CurrentSheet.ShowAllData

'Assign names to appropriate list boxes
With MainSelectionForm
.ListBox2.RowSource = RA_Range ****** errors here 
.ListBox1.RowSource = Comp_Range

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to assign `RA_Range.Address` to `RowSource` as a `Range` is an object.

Here's a very simple example of RowSource usage
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251646.aspx

Information about the Properties of Range (halfway down)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197454.aspx

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: I was able to get past the error but when I look at my listbox I can select areas but no words appear. Does .Address conflict with pulling over the words?

Comment: Sorry, looks like my misinterpretation of how to use RowSource; .Address returns a string containing the Address of the Range. A little more investigation shows http://stackoverflow.com/a/30933151/4541045 seems to be the same trouble you're having and may be enlightening. It appears that RowSource is expecting the full sheet name and range, but nothing a little string hackery can't fix.. I'll update my answer if that fixes it for you - nothing like a complete solution!