# Listbox displays any active sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 **userforms**, an homepage to select sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet 3...) in a workbook and also a page to make entries into the selected sheet. On the other page which is meant for making entries, I have a **listbox** which I want to use to display current data in any selected sheets in the homepage. I got a code which will allow the **combobox** at the homepage display sheets currently in the workbook but the problem is that I couldn't write a code populate data from the selected sheet in homepage into the **listbox** in the 2nd page.

The code used to display sheets in the workbook into the combobox at the homapage is given below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   Dim sh As Worksheet
   For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   Me.cboUsername.AddItem sh.Name

   Next sh

End Sub
```

I tried the following lines to make sheets display on the listbox in the second page but it didn't work:

```
Private Sub TicketUserForm_Initialize()
   lstDisplay.RowSource = Sheets(Homepage.cboUsername.Value)
   lstDisplay.ColumnCount = 9
End Sub
```

The attached links contains a preview of the pages described.

[The Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OBHa.jpg)
[The second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcDXH.jpg)

Comment: You need something like `ListBox1.RowSource = "SheetName!RangeAddress"`. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932787/userform-listbox-rowsource-not-populating)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Thank you for your suggestion. However, it only addresses a particular sheet but I need a code that will allow listbox to populate data from any selected sheet

Comment: Like @SiddharthRout said, you need to specify the range, so something like this: `lstDisplay.RowSource = Sheets(Homepage.cboUsername.Value).Range("A1:E5")`. With a ColumnCount of 5 would display 5 columns (and 5 rows) with the values in the Cells A1 to E5.