# How to create a Listbox with dynamic Rowsource in VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, listbox

I get an error called (Run-time error '13' ; Type mismatch).
Im new to VBA so sorry if this is a stupid question.

BaseForm = my userform

Dim iRow & iCol as integer

Sub refresh_data() ' refresh the listbox data

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
iCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 
With BaseForm

    .ListBox1.ColumnCount = iCol
    .ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
    
    If iRow > 1 Then
    .ListBox1.RowSource = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(iRow, iCol))
    
    Else
    .ListBox1.RowSource = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, iCol))

    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Try somehting like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932787/userform-listbox-rowsource-not-populating)

Answer (score 0):

1. When dealing with Excel rows, use `Long` instead of `Integer`
2. Fully qualify your range objects. You many want to read up on [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)
3. The `.RowSource` expects a `String`

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

Sub refresh_data() ' refresh the listbox data
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")

    iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    iCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 
    With BaseForm
        .ListBox1.ColumnCount = iCol
        .ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
    
        If iRow > 1 Then
            .ListBox1.RowSource = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & _
                                  ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)).Address
        Else
            .ListBox1.RowSource = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & _
                                  ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, iCol)).Address
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the fast reply! It was very helpful