How to use Worksheets Variables in RowSource?
Sub empRecListDisplay()
    Dim empMasterList As Worksheet
    Dim last_rowMasterlist As Long
    
    Set empMasterList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EMPLOYEE MASTERLIST")
    last_rowMasterlist = empMasterList.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With mainForm.EmpRecListBox
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 9
        .ColumnWidths = "100,350,100,100,100,100,100,100,100"
        .RowSource = empMasterList.Range("B1:K1").Address
    End With
End Sub


Address(External:=True) to make sure you're pointing at the correct worksheet.

See previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932787/userform-listbox-rowsource-not-populating

Range("B1:K"&last_rowMasterlist) but it should be J not K looking at ColumnCount.

Side note:  last_rowMasterlist = empMasterList.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row is missing a qualification for empMasterList.Rows.Count.
